# return render method does not working in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Hi I am very new to the Django and trying to learn going through the vidoes&docs but stuck return the html page from templates.
Though posts/index.html exists, getting the error "TemplateDoesNotExist at /posts/"
not sure where did I wrong, please advise.
here are my directory structure
djangoproject/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^posts/', include('posts.urls')),
]
```

and Django app called "posts"
posts/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
]
```

posts/views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'posts/index.html')
```

posts/templates/posts/index.html

```
<h3>message from index.html</h3>
```

here is my TEMPLATES from settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'posts/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Is `posts` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: no, its not there